# set Interval in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am beginner in javascript.
There is strange thing in javascript and I feel stupid

```
//First statement
var myVar = "Hello";
function hello() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myVar;
}

//second statement
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Why the second function work without invoked it ?
Unlike the first ? This caused a lot of problems to me !

Comment: You are passing the function `myTimer` to `setInterval`. `setInterval` calls the function every 1000ms. So while it is not *you* who directly calls the function, it is still called.

Comment: You invoke it here : `var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);`

Comment: It's actually the inverse. You're calling the second function but not the first.

Comment: @Jean-maximeBouloc: no, that's merely *passing* the function to `setInterval`.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, wrong expression

Comment: @AmrElgendy, I don't see where `hello()` is being called. I do, however, see where `myTimer()` is being called.

Comment: Are you saying `hello` is somehow invoked? Not in your example. Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: but it still variable @Jean-maximeBouloc

Comment: @FelixKling  I remove the comment which I say that in it

Comment: Try code 
The first function didn't work

Comment: Of course the function "doesn't work". You are not calling it anywhere, nor are you doing anything that gets it invoked. Isn't it obvious that the difference between the first and the second example is that you are passing the second function to `setInterval`, but that you are not doing anything with the first function?

Comment: The question is right

Comment: ok , but why the second work ??

Comment: I'm sorry if I write anything wrong because I speak a little English

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: Ok all things good , but you mean that statement in variable excecute Automatically ???

Comment: Not quite, no. The whole point of `setInterval` is to call the function you are passing to it. That's what `setInterval` is implemented to do.

Comment: Thanks very much,  I understand everything

Comment: Maybe also important to know in this case: Functions are *values*, just like any other value. That means you can pass functions to other functions. That's what happens here with `setInterval`: it receives a function as argument and knows that it has to call that function ever x ms (the value of the second argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the second function work without invoked it ? Unlike the first ?

You are passing the function `myTimer` to `setInterval`. `setInterval` calls the function every 1000ms. So while it is not *you* who directly calls the function, it is still called (by `setInterval`). `setInterval`'s whole purpose is to call the function that you pass to it as argument.

In contrast, you are not doing anything with `hello`. You are neither calling it directly, nor are you passing it to any other function that could call it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from the comments, you seem to be confused as to why the `myTimer()` function works. Here's a brief explanation:

On this line

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
```

you are calling the `setInterval()` function. That function takes 2 parameters, which you have defined. The first one is a function; the code to be executed. The second one is the delay between each execution of said function.

On the next line, you have declared the variable `myTimer` to be a function which is executed with the `setInterval`.

Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for details. Specifically, it says:

> `var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay)`

The parameters are defined as:

> **func**: A function to be executed every delay milliseconds.

and

> **delay**: The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should delay in between executions of the specified function or code.

Comment: Yes , This is part of my question

Comment: Now I understand all , Thanks

Comment: @AmrElgendy, nice. glad I could help.